# How to remove all words between slash in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have string

```
x <- "('00111','22222', /*abd*/ '22343','24352' /*abdegsg*/)"
```

I want to remove characters between slash like

```
('00111','22222', '22343','24352')
```

Comment: I don't understand your input.  Is `x` a vector of strings or a single string?

Comment: X is single string. And there are some numbers between slashes therefore just extracting numbers is not a solution.

Comment: @racoon I gave you an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use library stringr to extract out all the numbers.

```r
x <- "('00111','22222', /*abd*/ '22343','24352' /*abdegsg*/)"

stringr::str_extract_all(x, "\\d+", simplify = T)
#>      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
#> [1,] "00111" "22222" "22343" "24352"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: There are numbers too between slashes therefore extracting only numbers can not be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can gsub like following

```
gsub(pattern = "/[a-zA-Z]*/", "", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `gregexpr` for a base R solution:

```
x <- "('00111','22222', /*abd*/ '22343','24352' /*abdegsg*/)"
m <- gregexpr("'\\d+'", x)
regmatches(x, m)[[1]]

[1] "'00111'" "'22222'" "'22343'" "'24352'"
```